# IBM MFP IOS Memory leaks

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, ibm-mobilefirst

I can see many memory leaks in the MFP IOS  SDK(8.0.2017022013) on every request. I uploaded a simple test project [here](https://bitbucket.org/kamirana/mfptest/overview) which implements a simple request. Below is the image where memory leaks are shown.

[image: leaksImage].

The main issue is when you create some models in the `completionHandler` where you get the response, it retains those models because i think `WLResourceRequest` is still holding the `completionHandler` block reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory leak issues for MFP iOS SDK 8.0.x has been worked upon , fixes will be available in upcoming iFix.

Answer (score 1):

Please open a PMR with IBM MobileFirst team to track and fix this case.